# Handling thousands of product variations within WooCommerce.

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, product

I have a client that has products with thousands of variations per product, ranging from 14,000, all the way up to 100,000+, for example, some products have 12 attributes, with around 5 terms within them.

I have a plugin at the moment that works out all the costs and creates the variations for you, and this works fine for products with 0-5000 variations, but not the larger ones.
My problem is, when I create these products with high amounts of variations, the site becomes unresponsive and unusable.

Are there any work arounds? Or is WooCommerce simply not the right platform for this?

**Here are my enviroment details:**

#### Server Environment

Server Info: Apache
PHP Version: 5.6.31
PHP Post Max Size: 8 MB
PHP Time Limit: 60
PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
cURL Version: 7.55.1
OpenSSL/1.0.2k

#### Server Environment

WC version: 3.1.2
WP version: 4.8.2
WP memory limit: 1 GB

Any help is appricated, thanks.

Comment: WooCommerce can handle it. It's likely some optimisation is needed.

Are your product images compressed?

Try the jetpack extension to deliver the images.

Comment: My experience with WooCommerce has been that it begins to get sluggish at large volumes of products, and I'm guessing that extends to large volumes of variations as well.  100k variations for a product is pretty insane, honestly.  Further, you're going to have serious problems if you allow WP to use 1G of memory - as soon as you get multiple visitors on the site, it's going to bring down the server.

Comment: Are you using MyISAM tables by any chance? Table-level locks would explain the whole site becoming unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be possible but you have to change `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` to higher values in **php.ini**.
For example, I was able to import ~4300 variaton SKUs at once with the next settings:

```
max_execution_time = 1200
memory_limit = 256M
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Woocommerce can't handle this.